# Looping a sql statement if more than 1 record found

Tags: php, sql, loops

I'm trying to check if a certain record meet the following condition: status is "File Closed", not_visible = "0" and status_date is earlier by 14 days or more.

If condition met, to update not_visible "0" to "1".

This is invoke whenever a user logs in.

Problem:
The sql only run once even if 10 records found. How do I loop it to complete updating all records found and exit the statement once done?

```
global $conn;
$strSQLExists = "select lead_id as a, status_date as b, not_visible as c from tbl_progress where status = 'File Closed' and not_visible = '0' and status_date <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -14 DAY)  ";
$rsExists = db_query($strSQLExists,$conn);
$data=db_fetch_array($rsExists);
if($data)
{
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_progress SET not_visible = '1' WHERE lead_id = '".$data["a"]."'";
CustomQuery($sql);
return false;
}
else
{
    // if dont exist do something else
}
```

Was adviced to just update:
so here we are:

```
UPDATE tbl_progress SET not_visible = '1' WHERE status = 'File Closed' and not_visible = '0' and status_date <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -14 DAY)
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Also, why do you `select` first? Just do an `update`.

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to insert values into SQL, use parameters. In this case avoids the need to format the value, more generally it will save you when hostile data slips through.

Comment: The advantage of making it one statement (an UPDATE) is that it updates all of the records that match your criteria in one statement.  This is something that's useful to learn now!

Comment: @melpomene so i will just do this? 

UPDATE tbl_progress SET not_visible = '1' WHERE status = 'File Closed' and not_visible = '0' and status_date <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -14 DAY)

Answer (score 0):

Doing it using update statement only (as per your edit) should fix the issue. Actually, using update fixes

1. the looping issue, as it updates all records that match, not just one
2. the sql injection issue, as there are no parameters passed around and no string concatenation of the sql statement
3. the race condition issue that might occur if something was changed between select and update

It will also be slightly more efficient, as it pushes the logic to db.

In short: using an update instead of select + update will fix the looping issue and some other issues you didn't know you had, so use that.